# error when installing Repast HPC 2.0

Tags: repast-simphony, repast-hpc

Has anyone tried Repast HPC 2.0. I am trying to install it on Mint 16 (64-bit) but got errors as below:

```
mkdir -p ../include/repast_hpc
mkdir -p ../include/relogo
cp ../src/repast_hpc/*.h ../include/repast_hpc/
cp ../src/relogo/*.h ../include/relogo/
mkdir -p ../bin
cp ../src/rumor_model/config.props ../bin/rumor_config.props
cp ../src/rumor_model/model.props ../bin/rumor_model.props
/usr/bin/mpicxx -L../lib/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ ../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o ../src/rumor_model/main.o -lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf -lrepast_hpc-2.0 -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o ../bin/rumor_model
../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o: In function `RumorModel::init()':
RumorModel.cpp:(.text+0xd37): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::operator int() const'
../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o: In function `void boost::mpi::detail::reduce_impl<int, std::plus<int> >(boost::mpi::communicator const&, int const*, int, int*, std::plus<int>, int, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>)':
RumorModel.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3mpi6detail11reduce_implIiSt4plusIiEEEvRKNS0_12communicatorEPKT_iPS8_T0_iN4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEESF_[_ZN5boost3mpi6detail11reduce_implIiSt4plusIiEEEvRKNS0_12communicatorEPKT_iPS8_T0_iN4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEESF_]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::operator int() const'
../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o: In function `void boost::mpi::detail::reduce_impl<int, std::plus<int> >(boost::mpi::communicator const&, int const*, int, std::plus<int>, int, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>)':
RumorModel.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3mpi6detail11reduce_implIiSt4plusIiEEEvRKNS0_12communicatorEPKT_iT0_iN4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEESE_[_ZN5boost3mpi6detail11reduce_implIiSt4plusIiEEEvRKNS0_12communicatorEPKT_iT0_iN4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEESE_]+0x21): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::operator int() const'
../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o: In function `void boost::mpi::detail::broadcast_impl<double>(boost::mpi::communicator const&, double*, int, int, mpl_::bool_<true>)':
RumorModel.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3mpi6detail14broadcast_implIdEEvRKNS0_12communicatorEPT_iiN4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEE[_ZN5boost3mpi6detail14broadcast_implIdEEvRKNS0_12communicatorEPT_iiN4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEE]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::operator int() const'
../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o: In function `boost::mpi::request boost::mpi::communicator::irecv_impl<repast::Request_Packet<NodeContent> >(int, int, repast::Request_Packet<NodeContent>&, mpl_::bool_<false>) const':
RumorModel.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost3mpi12communicator10irecv_implIN6repast14Request_PacketI11NodeContentEEEENS0_7requestEiiRT_N4mpl_5bool_ILb0EEE[_ZNK5boost3mpi12communicator10irecv_implIN6repast14Request_PacketI11NodeContentEEEENS0_7requestEiiRT_N4mpl_5bool_ILb0EEE]+0x92): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::operator int() const'
../src/rumor_model/RumorModel.o:RumorModel.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost3mpi12communicator10isend_implIN6repast14Request_PacketI11NodeContentEEEENS0_7requestEiiRKT_N4mpl_5bool_ILb0EEE[_ZNK5boost3mpi12communicator10isend_implIN6repast14Request_PacketI11NodeContentEEEENS0_7requestEiiRKT_N4mpl_5bool_ILb0EEE]+0x25): more undefined references to `boost::mpi::communicator::operator int() const' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../bin/rumor_model] Error 1
```

I installed all the required dependencies, namely, C++, make, mpicxx, boost, curl and netcdf through apt-get and changed the addresses of libraries in the makefile as below:

```
CXX=/usr/bin/mpicxx
CXXLD=/usr/bin/mpicxx
BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/
BOOST_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib/
BOOST_INFIX=
NETCDF_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/        
NETCDF_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib/
CURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include/
CURL_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib/
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I recently met this problem with linking the serialization. I solve this by using the latest version of boost (v1.59 now).